# Flask JWT to SQLAlchemy User Object?

Tags: authentication, flask, sqlalchemy, jwt, authorization

I have an app where the user details are passed as a JWT containing information about the current user and it's roles.
Everytime the user is logged in (via a KeyCloak instance), the information from the JWT is parsed on my end in a function that updates the user object via `SQLAlchemy`. However, since there is no user object being passed back and forth in the backend, I have to parse the JWT for roles for every action that requires it. I also have a need for auditing, and due to the structure of the app, this module does not necessarily have access to the request objects at the time of logging.

I'm looking for a neat way to make something like `flask_user`s `current_user()` functionality work by mapping JWT -> ORM user object, to be able to transparently get the current user. Is there any way to go about this? The user registration and so on is completely separate from the app, and `Flask` only knows which user it is based on tokens in the requests that are being sent.

TLDR; Is there a way to load a user from the DB based on an already issued JWT (which contains information to map to a user), and is there perhaps already a lib or extension to flask that supports this?

Answer (score 0):

I use a decorator to parse the JWT token using `pyjwt`.

Then from the parsed token you can get the user and do the proper authorization.

If you don't want to add the decorator to all your functions that require authorization you can use Flasks `before_request`.

```py
from functools import wraps

from flask import Response, current_app, request
from jwt import decode
from jwt.exceptions import (DecodeError, ExpiredSignatureError,
                            InvalidSignatureError)

def authorize(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def check_authorization(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            jwt_token = request.cookies.get('auth_token') # get token from request
            if jwt_token is None:
                return Response(status=401, headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer'})
            
            token = decode(
                jwt_token,
                key='pub_key', # public key to validate key
                algorithms=['RS256'], # list of algs the key could be signed 
                verify=True
            )
            
            # you can call another function to do check user roles here
            # e.g authorize(token['sub'])
            
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (InvalidSignatureError, DecodeError, ExpiredSignatureError):
            return Response(
                response='{ "error": "token_invalid"}',
                status=401,
                headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer'})
    return check_authorization
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supported with flask-jwt-extended: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/complex_objects_from_token/